# counting the number of time a pattern occurs in files

Tags: python, awk

this is my file:

```
$ cat file
some pile of text
or other
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
   <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">

    <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
  </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
and more maybe.
```

this is the pattern I am trying to match:

```
$ cat old
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
   <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">

    <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
  </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to see how many times a pattern in a file happens in other files(*.html). I am looking to do this using awk and/or python.

So for example given this 1 file here the answer would be 1 something like:(I may have to use a for loop and awk on each iteration)

```
awk ... file
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='^$' 'NR==FNR{RS=$0} END{print (FNR && (RT=="") ? FNR-1 : FNR)}' old file
```

The above reads the entire contents of `old` at one time exactly as-is and populates `RS` with that string before moving onto read `file`. `FNR` in the `END` block represents the number of `RS`-terminated strings present in `file`. If the end of `file` does not end with a `RS` then there will be one string in the file after the last occurrence of `RS` and `RT` will be the null string. In that case if `FNR` is non-zero you subtract 1 to get the number of `RS`s that were seen. You need to check for non-zero `FNR` to avoid printing `-1` for an empty file.

So at the end of the file if FNR != 0 then the file was not empty so then you need to check if the file ended with an RS (in which case RT will be non-null) or not (in which case RT will be null). If it did then the number of RSs seen is FNR, otherwise it's FNR-1. And if FNR == 0 then the file was empty so you want to print a count of zero.

Comment: tks, seems like a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
with open('old.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    search=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

print data.count(search)
```